# Firefox keeps giving error 0x80004005 with Redactor.min.js

Tags: ajax, firefox, jquery, wysiwyg

When I am using redactor in Firefox(only Firefox).

The console keeps giving me the error 0x80004005 for random script.

For example, if I have facebook's sdk in my page, the error will from that jssdk,

If i delete the sdk, the error will from the Redactor.min.js through...

Here is all the ajax stuff I have in Redactor.min.js

```
handler: function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.opts.handler,
                type: 'post',
                data: 'redactor=' + escape(encodeURIComponent(this.getCode())),
                success: $.proxy(function(data)
                {
                    this.setCode(data);
                    this.syncCode();

                }, this)
            });

        },



// dragupload
                if ($('#redactor_file').size() !== 0)
                {
                    $('#redactor_file').dragupload(
                    {
                        url: this.opts.imageUpload,
                        success: $.proxy(this.imageUploadCallback, this)
                    });
                }

                // ajax upload
                this.uploadInit('redactor_file', { auto: true, url: this.opts.imageUpload, success: $.proxy(this.imageUploadCallback, this)  });

                $('#redactor_upload_btn').click($.proxy(this.imageUploadCallbackLink, this));

            }, this);

            this.modalInit(RLANG.image, this.opts.path + '/plugins/image.html', 570, handler, true);

        },


$.ajax({
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'get',
                url: url,
                success: $.proxy(function(data)
                {...
```

Comment: Do you have a link for it? It would help...

Comment: @Robyflc I'm sorry I don't. But here is the javascript i cited from other site: https://www.likeplum.com/assets/95b7164c/redactor.js

Comment: Look like it works fine in the Redactor.js 's official site even with Firefox...

Comment: I use redactor too and it works fine in all browsers.
Check if it's being loaded properly before you call it from the code.

Comment: @Robyflc thanks for your help. Can u explain a little bit more? I think I load it properly because it works fine in Chrome IE Safari and Opera.

Comment: The best suggestion I can give you without being able to check it myself is that you should try to access it using FF from other computers since it seems that the problem is with you FF.